PSpice Error: Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving V_Vin
I'm trying to simulate the circuit in Pspice; the first few times it worked. However, I got an error when I tried to create a new page and copy all the circuits on it in order to do some circuit modification.
After this, I tried to get everything back to the way it was, but the simulation failed again and again.


Here is a part of the error discription.
INFO(ORPSIM-16531): Installing model GAN.

INFO(ORPSIM-16531): Installing model HICUM0.

INFO(ORPSIM-16531): Installing model VBIC.

ERROR(ORPSIM-15143): Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving V_Vin. You may break the loop by adding a series resistance

Thank you in advance! This error almost drove me mad.

If you copy the entire circuit, then your labeled nodes Vin and Vout will be shorted together between the copies. You need to make sure to relabel these nodes after copying.

Thank you! I never knew that before. Let me try it.

It works! You save me mate! Thank you!
